# decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I am using JetBrains GoLand and I am trying to debug my go file and I am getting the following error:

> decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short

I tried to find an answer here at StackOverflow but unfortunately, I didn't get any solution.

Comment: Are you using Go 1.11? If so, maybe try updating Goland or Delve? Go 1.11 made some changes to the DWARF information.

Comment: Thank you @MartinTournoij, I updated Goland and delve and it works!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GoLand ships with a bundled version of Delve. Update to 2018.2.2 and it should work. If you need to do remote debugging, then you need to update your Delve installation on/for the target machine as well (make sure you compile it with Go 1.11).

Edit:
There are two more possible cases where this issue can appear:

- the application was compiled with all the debugging flags turned off and the additional debugging information stripped
- the application uses the standard library "plugin" package, which is known to cause an issue in the Go compiler. This will be fixed in Go 1.12.

Comment: I had the same issue after updateing Go. Delve update helped: `go get -u github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv`

Comment: GoLand ships with its own delve copy so updating the external version should not change anything.

Comment: Yes, I know Go ships with its own Delve copy, but the wierd thing is that I had this issue exactly after updateing Go. Everything started working again only after `go get -u github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv`

Comment: For me it is located in `$GOPATH/bin`

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share my experience here too as it may be helpful for community, I made it works by doing the following:

- Update Goland to `18.3`
- Also, in case if you have Mac, you should run `xcode-select --install`
- In case if you had `delv` already installed inside `GOPATH/bin`, remove it and re-install it again by following instructions [here](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/tree/master/Documentation/installation)

Answer (score 2):

For my Mac the problem is related to the dlv package as installed by Golang plugin.

- Install [delv](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/tree/master/Documentation/installation) and,
- check the path of dlv as executed by IntelliJ (in the console).

Go to this directory

```
($HOME//Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.3/intellij-go/lib/dlv/mac)
```

- and rename dlv to any other name. Get the right dlv executable by using

  ```
  which dlv (/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/bin/dlv for my computer)
  ```
- and add a symbolic link

  ```
  (ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/bin/dlv dlv).
  ```

Comment: You should just upgrade the IDE and this will work. Adding the symlinks will break the updater functionality, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of effort, I was able to find the issue. It was due to Golang Plugin which is deprecated and was not compatible with IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2 (Ultimate Edition).

I uninstalled the plugin and reinstall the IntelliJ.
Hope this also helps to above solutions.