# Unable to debug Go code: could not launch process: decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short

Tags: go, delve

we are trying to debug Go code and getting this error:

```
could not launch process: decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short
```

our settings:

```
WITSC02X6385JGH:orderer sjain68$ uname -a
Darwin WITSC02X6385JGH 17.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Fri Jul  6 19:54:51 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.3~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
WITSC02X6385JGH:orderer sjain68$ go version
go version go1.11 darwin/amd64
WITSC02X6385JGH:orderer sjain68$ dlv version
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.1.0
Build: $Id: 1990ba12450cab9425a2ae62e6ab988725023d5c
```

Things we have tried:

- Update dlv using VS Code -> Go: Install/Update Tools

Try running from command line:

```
WITSC02X6385JGH:orderer sjain68$ /Users/sjain68/go/bin/dlv debug github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer --headless=true --listen=127.0.0.1:41305 --api-version=2 --log=true --
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:41305
INFO[0002] launching process with args: [/Users/sjain68/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/debug]  layer=debugger
debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-902.0.79.7
 for x86_64.
Got a connection, launched process /Users/sjain68/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/debug (pid = 9278).
Exiting.
could not launch process: decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short
```

Note that the binary that we are trying to debug does gets executed. Its just that the debugger does not launch.

Another thing we tried from [this](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1138) link:

```
WITSC02X6385JGH:orderer sjain68$ export GOFLAGS="-ldflags=-compressdwarf=false"; dlv debug
could not launch process: decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short
```

Someone said to run GOCACHE=off go build ... and output of that is pasted [here](https://gist.github.com/siddjain/50013fc545ed22d3f5766677f20839db).

How can we fix this?

Comment: Did you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230503/decoding-dwarf-section-info-at-offset-0x0-too-short)?

Comment: Yes we have. Is there anything in that answer that we have not tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for us was to upgrade Go version

```
$ go version
go version go1.13.3 darwin/amd64
```

So Go 1.11 is the culprit.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue after updateing Go.
Updating Delve package from console helped:

```
go get -u github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you aren't using flags that remove the debug info from your build ie -ldflags="-s -w" .

https://lukeeckley.com/post/useful-go-build-flags/