# Delve (dlv) is not able to attach to the process

Tags: debugging, go, build, delve

I'm getting this error back from dlv

```
could not attach to pid 20727: decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short
```

The binary is built in this way:

```
go build -a -v -ldflags "-w -X main.gitCommit=<sha> -linkmode 'auto' -extldflags '-static'"
```

Could you confirm that is the `-w` flag that cause the following issue? Does it strip the debug symbol?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230503/decoding-dwarf-section-info-at-offset-0x0-too-short)

Comment: @daplho not a duplicate. I'm not using Goland at all

Comment: I know that but there is a chance the underlying issue is the same.

Comment: Also this question from yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333761/unable-to-debug-go-code-could-not-launch-process-decoding-dwarf-section-info-a - are you running this on Mac?

Answer (score 3):

After I've removed the `-w` flag delve was able to attach to the process